# How do I delete a directory that appears to contain nameless files?

Tags: linux, reiserfs

I'm trying to delete a supposedly empty directory on a ReiserFS filesystem, but I can't because `rm` keeps complaining that the directory isn't empty.

```
$ rm -rf thedirectory
rm: cannot remove `thedirectory': Directory not empty
$ ls -a thedirectory
         .  ..
```

The problem is, everything I do to try to determine what actually *is* in the directory seems to show that there are three files *with no names*. For example:

```
$ cd thedirectory
$ ls
ls: cannot access : No such file or directory
ls: cannot access : No such file or directory
ls: cannot access : No such file or directory

$ find .
.
./
./
./
$ ls -N | cat -A
$
$
$
```

Since I can't get filenames, I can't run `stat` or anything useful on these mystery files. A `stat` on the directory itself yields seemingly normal results:

```
$ stat .
  File: `.'
  Size: 192             Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 807h/2055d      Inode: 825484      Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/ diazona)   Gid: ( 1000/ diazona)
Access: 2012-01-27 16:32:45.000000000 -0500
Modify: 2012-01-27 16:31:58.000000000 -0500
Change: 2012-01-27 16:31:58.000000000 -0500
```

I suppose some kind of filesystem corruption is involved, which probably means I have to shut down, boot from a live USB drive, and try my luck with `reiserfsck`. But is there any easier way to deal with this?

Comment: Have you tried `rm -rf /path/to/thedirectory`?

Comment: Silly me, I completely forgot to include that output ;-) but yes, that was what brought my attention to the problem in the first place.

Comment: What does `ls -N | cat -A` print?

Comment: I've edited that into the question too.

Answer (score 1):

Giving the `-f` flag to rm means it won't complain when it can't do something, perhaps something such as trying to remove a file owned by another user (e.g. root) or you don't have write permissions to the directory.  `sudo rm -rf /path/to/thedirectory` will no doubt nuke the directory and the files therein.  `ls -B thedirectory | cat -ve` may also be illuminating.

Comment: No luck, running with `sudo` fails the same way.

Comment: Then you've got a fault in the filesystem.  fsck reports nothing amiss?

Comment: I haven't run fsck yet, because I need to unmount the filesystem first.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried deleting the inode directly?

```
$ ls -iN | cat -A
794539 $
$ find . -inum 794539 -exec rm -i {} \;
```

Comment: looking at the timestamp, i seem to be late to the party :-/

Comment: Sorry, I never noticed this here. I'm a little later in responding, I guess :-P I don't have access to the filesystem in question anymore, but I don't think this would work because it needs the filename to pass to `rm`. It _might_ have worked to use find's `-delete` option, and if I ever get the chance to test this, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all files with

```
ls -la /name/of/path
```

...which will give you a long listing, including any dot files.

To remove a directory and everything inside of it, including other subdirectories, use:

```
rm -rf /name/of/path/*
```

...although be careful if you plan to use the wildcard character, which leads to the (in)famous statement:

```
rm -rf *
```

...which is dangerous, indeed, even for "normal users".  If you ever need to use the wildcard character, I would suggest:

```
rm -rf /name/of/path
```

or

```
rm -rf ./*
```

... the last with the dot-slash being done with the assumption that you are "inside" the directory you want to empty out...you'll still need to move down one directory and remove it from outside of itself.