# Behaviour of "rm -r"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, rm

Up until now I was using Ubuntu, and the behaviour of `rm` for directories was the following:

- `rm -r dir` would remove `dir` if it was empty, and give an error otherwise
- `rm -rf dir` would remove `dir` and its contents recursively

It's possible that `rm` was aliased to something to behave this way, but I no longer have access to my Ubuntu system so I can't tell.

Now I switched to Linux Mint, and the behaviour is different: `rm -r` removes a directory and its contents recursively, just like `rm -rf` did on Ubuntu.

I looked at `rm`'s manpage on Linux Mint to try to find a combination of options that would reproduce the Ubuntu behaviour, but I couldn't find any.

My questions are:

- Why is the behaviour of `rm` different between Linux distributions? Isn't it a standard tool that should be the same everywhere?
- How do I achieve the behaviour described at the beginning of the question?

Comment: This is nonstandard behavior for rm.  I have never had rm behave this way on Ubuntu, Red Hat, SuSE, or any other mainstream distro that I've used.  Are you sure you weren't using rmdir instead?

Comment: @rob: Quite sure. I will investigate next time I'm at a Ubuntu system with this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible that `rm` was aliased to something on your Ubuntu system (in .bashrc, for example). `rm -r` deletes the dir and it's contents for me on Ubuntu 12.04. `rm -f` needs to be used for cases where there are different permissions on the content of the dir (for example, read-only files).

Comment: Do you have any idea of what `rm` might have been aliased to on my Ubuntu system to get the behaviour I described? I looked at `man rm` on my Linux Mint system but couldn't find any options that would yield that behaviour.

Comment: What error did you get when you ran `rm -r <dir>` on a directory with content inside it?

Comment: The error was: `rm: cannot remove '<dir>': Directory not empty`.

Comment: Perhaps it could have been a filesystem error on your Ubuntu machine? See: http://superuser.com/questions/383221/how-do-i-delete-a-directory-that-appears-to-contain-nameless-files and http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/rm-cannot-remove-directory-%60ff'-directory-not-empty-298105/

Comment: No, I only got that message if the directory was in fact not empty.

Comment: I think default behavior is only to throw that error if a file is in use.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `rmdir` command, it will only remove empty directories